# Issue with excerpt showing in search results (wordpress theme)

Tags: php, wordpress

Last year i've created a website with the Wordpress theme Let's Travel. I now have an issue regarding the displayed search results and I hope someone has a solution. The search results look like this:

[Screenshot Searchresults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxZZ.jpg)

Looks ok, but i've marked the part that I don't want in there. That are the titles of the tabs on the actual page. I just want the first part of the actual text showing here. Or, even better: make this a custom excerpt (so it's using the excerpt you can create on every page by yourself).

The code providing this piece of information, looks like this:

```
<?php print wp_kses_post(Letstravel_TPL::clear_urls( wp_trim_words( wp_strip_all_tags(do_shortcode(get_the_excerpt())), 20 ) )); ?></p>
```

I've tried all kinds of different options with this code, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any tips regarding this issue? I am not very familiair with php, so I'm sorry if this is a very easy question :)

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the line of code completely?  Does it remove all of the text?

Comment: This part is strange: `do_shortcode(get_the_excerpt())` it looks like the theme must automatically put a shortcode in the excerpt.  Try adding `<?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>` somewhere above this and post the contents that it echoes.  Then we can track down the function that generates the output.

Comment: If I remove the line completely I get no text (just the title), which is already better than the previous situation. If I add <?php echo get_the_excerpt();?> it looks really weird: http://imgur.com/2Bpwljr
It shows much more parts of the actual post.